# Unix Cron Jobs Working Algorithm

Tags: php, unix, cron

What does Unix Kernel do if cron job set for every minute is executing a file which takes time  more than 1 minute.

**For Example:**

I have following Shell Command to execute PHP Script every minute.

```
* * * * * php /home/user/public_html/script.php
```

And My PHP script consists SQL code to select emails from database and send mails to given Emails using for loop.

**Problem:** How the system kernel will response if my database consists thousands of mail which takes more than 1 minute to finish the 1st execution.

Answer (score 3):

It will execute it again, unless you take steps yourself to prevent more than one instance running. You can test it by running a script that does:

```
date >> /tmp/a
sleep 90
date >> /tmp/a
```

Comment: You meant e.g. if I have 10k mails in db and if it sends only 2k mails in 1 minute so it will stop executing and will process remaining 8k mails in next intervals of 2k mails every minute.

Comment: No, I mean it will carry on processing all 10k mails till it finishes, and 1/5th the way through it will start another job that overlaps and does it all over again in parallel.

Comment: bit confusing but i think i understood.

Comment: @Hsaka, all cron does is start a process at a given time.  It will then run to completion as it would if started manually.  If cron starts it again a minute later, it will run as a completely separate process.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Reduce the cron frequency - to ensure the jobs finish
2. Use a lock to prevent the job from being executed while it is running.

We often use option two and simply write a lock flag to the DB or to the filesystem - and then clear it once the script has completed.